# Correct way to reshape tensor for keras w tensorflow backend

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, reshape

been a while since i did any neural networks. i'm coding a simple example as a warm up and am confused why my tensor is not shaped correctly.  i thought the model expected (samples, height, width, channels).

when i call

```
X_train.shape
```

i get (784, 100, 100, 3)

however i get an error: ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_10 to have shape (2,) but got array with shape (1,)

here's the simple model below. where am i going wrong? do i need to convert to grey scale?

```
#THE MODEL#
batch_size = 32
nb_classes = 2
nb_epoch = 2

img_rows =100
img_cols=100
img_channels = 3

model_input=Input(shape=(img_rows, img_cols,img_channels))

x = Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, border_mode='same')(model_input)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = Convolution2D(32, 3, 3)(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
x = Dropout(0.25)(x)
conv_out = Flatten()(x)

x1 = Dense(nb_classes, activation='softmax')(conv_out)


lst = [x1]

#model = Model(input=model_input, output=lst)
model = Model(input=model_input, output=lst) #I learned you can't use a sequential model for this type of prediction

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
optimizer='adam',
metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, nb_epoch=nb_epoch, callbacks=[history],verbose=1)
```

prior to running the model, i did this:

```
print('X_train shape:', X_train.shape)
print('y_train shape:', X_train.shape)
print(X_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(X_test.shape[0], 'test samples')
```

gave this output:

```
X_train shape: (784, 1, 100, 100, 3)
y_train shape: (784, 1, 100, 100, 3)
784 train samples
196 test samples
```

i then reshaped as so:

```
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 100,100, 3)

X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')
X_train /= 255 #normalize our data values to the range [0, 1], 255 is the max value of X_train.max()
X_test /= 255
```

then i get this shape for X_train

```
(784, 100, 100, 3)
```

the data was colored pics of fruit from kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/moltean/fruits

Comment: I ran that code just fine, the error must be somewhere else.

Comment: Can confirm that this code runs fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be batch size conflict. As far as the code snippet you shared looks like it should work just fine.

But the `X_train.shape` gives us the output tuple to be (784, 100, 100, 3). In this case I would initialize the input to be something like this:

```
model_input = Input(shape=(X_train.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols,img_channels))
```

Note: If you want to do variable batch size initialize the input with None and dynamically set value at the time of training. Cheers!

Comment: It is very unlikely that batch_size is the problem. The error does not mention the batch_size (i.e. 784) anywhere in it.

Comment: Yeah it could be, good catch. So it could be the `conv_out = Flatten()(x)` its a shape mismatch. what is your thought on this @thushv89?

Comment: @Mahesh when i initialize the input as you suggested i get this error: ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_29: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5.  any other info i can provide? like how i created the pixel arrays or anything?

Answer (score 0):

i was being an idiot. the error was because i did not encode my y_train.  i thought i already had but i hadn't. thanks to all who helped out!

```
y_train=np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, n_class)
y_test=np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, n_class)
```